# How can I store the set pattern lock in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application, flutter-plugin

I want to set own pattern lock in my flutter app and want to open the app later with same lock . I'm using a pattern lock plugin to set the pattern. How can I store the pattern/pin lock ?

I thought to use shared preferences plugin but didn't understand how to use it ?
I'm expecting to use the set pattern lock when I open my Flutter app next time. So how can I securely store and retrieve it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While storing the pattern directly in Shared Preferences is not recommended due to security concerns, here's a secure approach to achieve your goal:

1. Secure Storage:

Use a secure storage plugin like flutter_secure_storage or key_value_store. These plugins offer encrypted storage and access control mechanisms.
2. Pattern Hashing:

Instead of storing the actual pattern, generate a unique hash of the pattern using a strong hashing algorithm like SHA-256 or Argon2.
This ensures the pattern itself is never stored in plain text.
3. Storage and Retrieval:

When the user sets the pattern:
Hash the pattern.
Store the hash in the secure storage plugin.
When the user attempts to unlock the app:
Retrieve the stored hash.
Generate a new hash from the entered pattern.
Compare the two hashes. If they match, unlock the app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you !! Your answer worked for me to resolve my issue.